# Can't access specific website

Tags: website

So I can for some reason no longer login to https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home

I simply get redirected to a long url (https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?openid.assoc_handle=aws&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fsignin.aws.amazon.com%2Foauth%3Fresponse_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3Darn%253Aaws%253Aiam%253A%253A015428540659%253Auser%252Fhomepage%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fconsole.aws.amazon.com%252Fconsole%252Fhome%253Fnc2%253Dh_m_mc%2526state%253DhashArgs%252523%2526isauthcode%253Dtrue%26noAuthCookie%3Dtrue&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&action=&disableCorpSignUp=&clientContext=&marketPlaceId=&poolName=&authCookies=&pageId=aws.ssop&siteState=unregistered%2Cen_us&accountStatusPolicy=P1&sso=&openid.pape.preferred_auth_policies=MultifactorPhysical&openid.pape.max_auth_age=120&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&server=%2Fap%2Fsignin%3Fie%3DUTF8&accountPoolAlias=&forceMobileApp=0&forceMobileLayout=0)

And I get `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`

It works from my phone on same network I've tried chrome, IE and Firefox, also incognito modes and the address isn't blocked in my host file. I'm using windows 8.

Please help me before I go insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I didn't use the default DNS, I used one from the service http://www.unblock-us.com/ in order to view netflix on different regions. When I changed the DNS everything worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a possible security software issue. Try rebooting into safe mode with networking, and see if it works properly there. If so, you probably have something like zonealarm, or maybe a piece of malware manipulating traffic.